# no se como separar los datos concatenados de PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Que tal? estoy dando vueltas con un tema:

```
while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($respuesta)) {

str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[0]);
$row[1];
$row[2];
$row[3]->format('H:i:s');

echo 'data:' . str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[0]) . $row[1] . $row[2]. $row[3]- 
>format('H:i:s') . "\n\n";
ob_flush();
flush();}
```

como hago para que separar esos datos que estan en ROW, ya que al imprimirlos asi, me los manda todos juntos en un parrafo :/

```
  var eventList=document.getElementById('eventList');
var evtSource = new EventSource("sse.php");
var datoAnterior = 'LISTO PARA USAR';
var newElement = document.createElement ("p");
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    
    if ( datoAnterior != e.data){
        newElement.textContent = ` ${e.data}`;

        datoAnterior = e.data;
    } else {
        newElement.textContent = 'LISTO PARA USAR';
    }
    eventList.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

le di muchas vueltas, pero no se como hacerlo, si alguien me puede aconsejar de como podria ser. se lo agradecere mucho.

Comment: En vez de `\n` pon `<br>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo haria así:

```
$arr = [];
while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($respuesta)) {
  $arr[] = [
    'row0' => str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[0]),
    'row1' => $row[1],
    'row2' => $row[2],
    'row3' => $row[3]->format('H:i:s')
  ];
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Y luego, en tu javascript, los recogería con `JSON.parse();`. Es decir:

```
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  data = JSON.parse(e);
  console.log(data);
}
```

y luego los trataria como un array de objetos de javascript.

Comment: Gracias genios, me sirvio excelente

Comment: De nada, pero recuerda votar y aceptar siempre que alguna respuesta ha cumplido con tus pregunta, sino vas a demotivarnos para ayudarte las proximas veces. En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo cuando la respuesta cumplimenta tu pregunta.

Comment: perdon, no sabia de eso, soy nuevo en esta pag. ahi lo hice. gracias

Comment: Gracias, de este modo la respuesta que te ha servido gana visibilidad si alguien tiene un problema similar al tuyo y aparece por esta página a ver las respuestas. No tiene porque ser la mia por haberte dicho eso, sino la que realmente ha solucionado tu problema.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes tratarlo como un array dentro del while.

```
while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($respuesta)) {

str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[0]);
$row[1];
$row[2];
$row[3]->format('H:i:s');

$data["info"][] = array("row0"=>str_ireplace($desc_regular, $desc_nuevo, $row[0]), "row1"=>$row[1], "row2"=>$row[2], "row3"=>$row[3]->format('H:i:s'))

}

ob_flush();
flush();

echo json_encode($data);
```

Luego procesas los datos obtenidos en el archivo javascript, otra opcion es separar el texto que estas devolviendo desde del php con ";" para separarlos, posteriormente en el archivo javascript con split() puedes obtener datos individuales